# jquery.cascade-select.js catch the success event of .cascade() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In javascript/jquery, I have two dropdowns and one text field.  On selection of first dropdown, the second dropdown gets populated.  For this, I have used `jquery.cascade-select.js`.  And it works fine.

What I want is, **on success** of the cascade function, I need to set the value of the text field.

I tried setting the value in `$(document).ready()` function, but it is not satisfying my needs.

Is it possible to catch the success event of `.cascade()` function?

Comment: Which `jquery.cascade-select` are you using? Please link to the project

Comment: Am using this [jquery.cascade-select](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-cascade/source/browse/trunk/jquery.cascade-select.js?r=2)

Comment: You mean the callback from the ajax? No, there's currently no way to get it. But I'm sure you can extend the code with an optional parameter…

Comment: Yeah i meant the same. Thanks for your reply.